# openURL on local file in temporary directory does nothing

Tags: swift, openurl

I'm saving a downloaded PDF file to a temporary directory on my device, and have the URL for the resultant file:

```
file:///Users/colinbasnett/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A057DDAD-B116-424B-8383-442321530EEC/data/Containers/Data/Application/A0AEF93A-5B1D-4CB4-B39F-F6DFECEDD9E9/tmp/FF5C09A9-45CD-454E-B55A-4F5CEBFEBC7F-24875-000014B657DC6436/23659.pdf
```

Where `fileURL` is a valid `NSURL` object representing the path above, I call this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fileURL)
```

and nothing happens.

Despite this, the following call returns `true`:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fileURL)  // returns true
```

Ideally this would open in Safari or whatever the preferred browser application is. Interestingly enough, I can manually open Safari, paste that directory in the address bar and it is able to display the PDF.

I'm using Swift 2.2 (can't switch to 3 yet because dependencies have not been upgraded).

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this article (http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/) indicates openURL has been deprecated in iOS 10. Is that where you're running? They have code showing what you need to do (although in Swift 3, which you would need to convert back to 2.2).

Comment: No, I'm running it on an iPad 2 simulator on Xcode 7.3, so it's not simulating an iOS 10 device.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `openURL()` wants to launch a separate application, but you're passing a `file:` URL that points to a file in your sandbox. I suspect `UIDocumentInteractionController` might be more what you're after.